# Can php source code package a library like the java .jar?

Tags: java, php, jar, package

I package my source code in Java using .jar. Is there any things like that in php?? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest thing PHP is Phar: http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php

Answer (score 2):

there is phar.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php

Answer (score 1):

There are two:

[bcompiler](http://pecl.php.net/package/bcompiler) and
[phar](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php)

I actually asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457105/what-are-the-benefits-of-the-php-the-different-php-compression-libraries) regarding these, but I don't remember getting too many useful responses.